# How to use custom test-id in Playwright?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, playwright

In the HTML under test I have added my own locators for testing purposes, for example.

```
<input type="email" inputmode="email" data-pid="UserString" name="UserString" aria-label="User Email" />
```

And `data-pid="UserString"` being the locator in use, so in my selenium test suite we have this.

```
protected By UserString = By.CssSelector("[data-pid='UserString']");
```

And this

```
FillTextBox(UserString, "tester@tester.com");
```

This all works very nicely in C#/Selenium but I am not sure how to implement such a strategy in PLaywright. I can see the standard locator methods such as  getByText, name, id etc.

Is this possible and if yes can someone please tell me how.

Comment: What language are you using Playwright in? Please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AutomationAndy for his suggestion. That was spot on.
So basicly what I now have is this

```
private static ILocator UserString => Page.Locator("[data-pid='UserString']");
```

And this is called thus

```
await UserString.FillAsync("tester@testing.com");
```

Works a dream

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the best way is to use the `aria-label` you have there:

```
await page.GetByLabel("User Email").FillAsync("tester@tester.com");
```

Comment: You could also do `await page.locator('[data-pid=UserString]').FillAsync("tester@tester.com")` which is similar to your selenium code.

Comment: Thanks @AutomationAndy I will give that a try. Not all elements have aria-labels but all the required ones do have data-pid

Comment: hanks @AutomationAndy  that was just hat I needed, spot on

Answer (score 1):

You may also configure your own [custom test-id](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#set-a-custom-test-id-attribute) in Playwright:

```
//playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

    
    export default defineConfig({
      use: {
        testIdAttribute: 'data-pid'
      }
    });
```

And then locate the element as you would normally do:

```
await page.getByTestId('UserString').fill('tester@tester.com');
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#set-a-custom-test-id-attribute